# How can I open a new window using location.href but with vbscript

Tags: html, forms, validation, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a very old app that the scripting language is Vbscript, I nned to open a new window with location.href. How can I do that? is it possible?

Comment: Is it using VBScript as a client-side script (a la JavaScript) or on the server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's using VBScript as an alternative to JavaScript for client-side scripting then the DOM API is identical.

That said, you don't use `window.location` to open a new window, you use it to change the location of the current window.

[You open a popup window with `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). In VBScript I believe it's `Window.Open` (note the casing, but VBScript is case-insensitive so it shouldn't matter):

```
Sub OpenNewWindow

    Window.Open "http://somewhere", "_blank"
End Sub
```

- VBScript doesn't have parentheses for `Sub` (`void`) method calls as there is no return value.
- VBScript only uses double-quotes (`"`) to delimit strings

Comment: Thx u very much

Comment: There is also a modal window option too. if you need one - may be better than another window for some purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `location` object supplied by browsers is for accessing the location of the current window.

If you want to create a new window, you have to use the `open()` function.